# Java 8: unit-testing a method that returns a Function object

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to write a Java 8 unit test for a method that returns a `Function`; something like:

```
class MyObject<X> {
     public Function<X,Obj> getFunction() {...}
 }
```

In my unit test I create a sample Object and call `getFunction()` and want to compare that to the expected function which does not work with `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals`:

```
@Test
public void getFunction_returnsFunction() {
   final MyObject<St> object = new MyObject<>(..);
   final Function<St,Obj> expectedResult = ...;

   // this does not work
   assertEquals(expectedResult, object.getFunction());
}
```

Is it even possible to compare two `Function`s? How would you recommend to unit test this method?

Comment: What do you want to unit test about it? For example: it works without an exception, it returns non-null, it returns a function that yields X when you pass in Y...?

Comment: I want to test that it returns the correct Function.

Comment: But what is "the correct function"? Sure, you can test that it returns a specific instance, or an instance of a particular class, but then you're just duplicating your implementation.

Comment: The `Function` that is returned depends on some members of `MyObject`, and I want to test that the `Function` that is returned corresponds to the function I expect for the `MyObject` object.

Comment: If the functions should be _the same_, you could test `assertTrue(expected == object.getFunction());` but as noted, this seems kind of circular (just do whatever you do to get `expected` in `getFunction` itself?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the function behavior using the standard `R Function.apply(T t)` method:

```
Function<St,Obj> func = o.getFunction();
assertEquals(func.apply(value), expectedFunctionResult);
```

Comment: But this way I can only test the function for certain input values, but cannot assure that the function is correct for _all_ possible inputs, as far as I understand.

Comment: @AndreaRendl-Pitrey this isn't really any different to unit testing a regular method: you pass in some known inputs, you check the output is what you expect. It's up to you to choose those inputs so that they test salient behavior, e.g. boundaries.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I guess there is no better way to test the result than by using `Function.apply(T t)`. Thank you for your replies.